# Orientability vs $n$-frames via Stiefel-Whitney classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

I am trying to understand Stiefel-Whitney classes as obstructions for the existence of linearly independent sections of a vector bundle $E \to B$, that is a section of the Stiefel bundle $V_k (E) \to B$.

Ultimately I am interested in the problem of whether a vector bundle is trivialisable. This should be given by a section of the $n$-frames bundle $V_n (E) \to B$, where $n = \dim E$.

According to eg Hatcher, $w_i(E)$ is the mod 2 first obstruction to the existence of $n−i+1$ linearly independent sections of $E$. For $n=k$, the first Stiefel-Whitney class should measure the existence of $n$ linearly independent sections but what it measures is the orientability of $E$ (and there are many non-trivial orientable vector bundles out there).

Let me be more concrete about my questions:

1. Why does a section of $V_n (E) \to B$ determines an orientation of $E$ instead of a collection of $n$ linearly independent sections?
2. How to use the Stiefel-Whitney classes as obstructions for the existence of $n$ linearly independent sections (equivalently, to sufficient condition for the triviality of $E$)?

Comment: 1. A section of $V(E)$ assigns an ordered basis to each fiber of $p:E\rightarrow B$.

Comment: 2. $n-i+1$ independent sections of $E$ splits $E$ as the direct sum of a trivial bundle and a subbundle of dimension $i-1$. Use the Whitney sum formula for total Stieffel- Whitney , the triviality of the Stieffel-Whitney class of a trivial bundle, and the fact that $w_i$ of a bundle of dimension $i-1$ is zero.

Comment: What I believe you are saying in 1 is that a section of $V_n(E)$ determines $n$ linearly independent sections of $E  \to B$ (thus a trivialisation of $E$), but why isn't it the case?

Comment: It is the case.

Comment: Then what condition involving $V_n(E)$ expresses the orientability of $E$?

Comment: Note that the $k$-th SW class actually measures obstructions for the $k$-skeleton of the base. $w_1$ in particular would measure whether you can extend $n$ linearly independent sections from $B^0$ to $B^1$. However, this is not how it really works because $\pi_0$ is not a group, and this case has to be treated individually, for example by taking the local group of 0-homologies instead of $\pi_0$. In the end, what you arrive at will be orientability.

Comment: A section of the oriented $n$-frames is equivalent to being orientable.